# Reorder the elements in each row of a square diagonal matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a square symmetric matrix `A` of dimension `n` in Matlab and I want to reorder the elements in each row in ascending order but preserving the symmetry and without touching the diagonal elements.

E.g.

```
 n=4;
 A=[10 9 8 7; 9 6 5 4; 8 5 3 2; 7 4 2 1];
 %reorder A in order to obtain
 B=[10 7 8 9; 7 6 4 5; 8 4 3 2; 9 5 2 1];
```

Could you provide some help?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `triu` to sort only the upper triangle and then add the transpose to keep the symmetry. finally just set the diagonal as in the original matrix:

```
n=4;
A=[10 9 8 7; 9 6 5 4; 8 5 3 2; 7 4 2 1];
% upper triangle indexes
UI = triu(true(size(A)),1);
% upper triangle of A
B = triu(A,1);
% assign inf to diagonal and below - important if there are any negative values in A
B(~UI) = -inf;
% sort rows descending order
B = sort(B,2,'ascend');
% set infs to 0
B(isinf(B)) = 0;
% add lower triangle matrix
B = B + B.';
% set diagonal as original A
B(1:n+1:n^2) = diag(A)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think `B(~UI) = -inf;` and `B = sort(B,2);`

Comment: That's right, I thought you wanted descending order. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [10 9 8 7; 
      9 6 5 4; 
      8 5 3 2; 
      7 4 2 1];    
B = sort(triu(A,1),2) + diag(diag(A)) + sort(triu(A,1),2)';
```

Explain

`triu(A,1)` gets the upper triangular matrix above the main diagonal, that is

```
ans0 =

     0     9     8     7
     0     0     5     4
     0     0     0     2
     0     0     0     0
```

`sort(triu(A,1),2)` sorts the elements in each row of the above result in an ascending order, that is

```
ans1 =

     0     7     8     9
     0     0     4     5
     0     0     0     2
     0     0     0     0
```

`diag(diag(A))` gets the diagonal of `A`, that is

```
ans2 =

    10     0     0     0
     0     6     0     0
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     1
```

`sort(triu(A,1),2)'` gets the transpose of the sorted upper triangular matrix, that is

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0
     7     0     0     0
     8     4     0     0
     9     5     2     0
```

Add `ans1`, `ans2` and `ans3` up, you will get `B`.